# Redshift: cannot drop user owner default privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to delete an user from my database but I'm getting an error:

```
user "ted.mosby" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
Detail: owner of default privileges on new relations belonging to user ted.mosby in schema tv_shows
```

How can I fix this error and remove the user from my database?

I've changed owner and already revoked all permissions from `ted.mosby`.

Answer (score 4):

Revoke the default privileges:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER "ted.mosby" IN SCHEMA tv_shows
   REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM "ted.mosby";
```

You can use `\ddp` in `psql` to see if any default privileges are left.

Comment: Hi Laurenz - sorrry for the downvote. Will change to upvote if you change `ROLE` to `USER` (edit queue full right now). There are no such things as roles in Redshift: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html

Comment: @KarlAnka Thanks for the pointer; I have updated the answer. Crazy that they changed that.

Comment: Hi again Laurenz - I posted my own answer as I faced some permission issues following your answer. I would appreciate some input on my answer (or issue rather) - does Postgres behave in the same way as Redshift does here or have I just completely messed up my permission setup somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Redshift, as should have become obvious from the mistake in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

After being in contact with AWS Support and querying the table [`pg_default_acl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_DEFAULT_ACL.html) I realised that the user I wanted to drop had group default access privileges. So first I had to run:

```
alter default privileges for user "ted.mosby" grant EXECUTE on functions to public;
alter default privileges for user "ted.mosby" grant all on tables to "ted.mosby";
```

Then the following query:

```
select usename, acl.*
from pg_default_acl as acl join pg_user on usesysid = defacluser
where usename = 'ted.mosby';
```

showed me the groups in which the user was actually part of.

So if I tried the following

```
alter default privileges for user "ted.mosby" in schema my_schema 
revoke all on tables FROM group my_schema_group;
```

but I got a permission denied. So the workaround suggested from AWS Support was to temporary grant create permission for example, executing the above command and then removing the create permission, in this way:

```
grant create on schema my_schema to "ted.mosby";

alter default privileges for user "ted.mosby" in schema my_schema 
revoke all on tables FROM group my_schema_group;

revoke create on schema my_schema from "ted.mosby";
```

After the above queries, I queried again `pg_default_acl` with the same statement and I could see there was no more record for the removed group. As the user was part of different groups I had to execute it several times.

After removed from all groups I was able to successfully `drop user "ted.mosby"`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar error trying to drop a user when a schema the user had default privileges for had its owner previously transferred:

```
ERROR:  user "ted.moseby" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to user old_owner in schema my_schema
```

As a Super User running the following seems to work in my case:

```
grant create on schema my_schema to old_owner;
alter default privileges for user old_owner in schema my_schema revoke all on tables from ted.moseby;
revoke create on schema my_schema from old_owner;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but @Laurenz answer only partially helped me - I ran into permission issues as I had already transfered ownership on the schema from `ted.mosby` to my master user before revoking default privileges. **Long story short - revoke default privileges before transfering ownership.**

To reproduce my issue (I have no idea if this is a bug in Redshift or expected behaviour?):

```sql
-- executed with master user redshift_master
CREATE USER anton_test_user PASSWORD '***' IN GROUP redshift_dev;
```

Then using `anton_test_user`

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA anton_test_schema;
CREATE TABLE anton_test_schema.anton_test_table AS SELECT 1 AS anton;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA anton_test_schema 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP redshift_readonly;
```

Again with `redshift_master`

```sql
ALTER SCHEMA anton_test_schema OWNER TO redshift_master;
ALTER TABLE anton_test_schema.anton_test_table OWNER TO redshift_master;
```

Now trying to drop the user it complains about default privileges:

```sql
DROP USER anton_test_user;
```

Result as expected:

```sql
owner of default privileges on new relations belonging to user 
anton_test_user in schema anton_test_schema;
```

Now to the weird part, still with `redshift_master`

```sql
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER anton_test_user IN SCHEMA anton_test_schema
REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM redshift_readonly;
```

Gives `Invalid operation: permission denied for schema anton_test_schema`. What?

If running with `anton_test_user`

```sql
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA anton_test_schema
REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM redshift_readonly;
```

As well gives `Invalid operation: permission denied for schema anton_test_schema`.

The only way for me to solve this and being able to drop `anton_test_user` was to, with `redshift_master` drop the schema and table completely

```sql
DROP TABLE anton_test_schema.anton_test_table;
DROP SCHEMA anton_test_schema;
DROP USER anton_test_user; -- it works now
```

My completely uninformed guess is that `anton_test_user` had lost permissions to the schema, so no grants for the user could be applied or revoked in that schema.

Comment: droping users in redshift is a nightmare