# Unable to drop user because I cannot revoke default priviliges in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am having issues with dropping a user becauase it has default privileges, but I am as well unable to revoke those privileges.

To reproduce my issue:

```sql
-- executed with master user redshift_master
CREATE USER anton_test_user PASSWORD '***' IN GROUP redshift_dev;
```

Then using `anton_test_user`

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA anton_test_schema;
CREATE TABLE anton_test_schema.anton_test_table AS SELECT 1 AS anton;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA anton_test_schema 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP redshift_readonly;
```

Again with `redshift_master`

```sql
ALTER SCHEMA anton_test_schema OWNER TO redshift_master;
ALTER TABLE anton_test_schema.anton_test_table OWNER TO redshift_master;
```

Now trying to drop the user it complains about default privileges:

```sql
DROP USER anton_test_user;
```

Result as expected:

```sql
owner of default privileges on new relations belonging to user 
anton_test_user in schema anton_test_schema;
```

Now to the weird part, still with `redshift_master`

```sql
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER anton_test_user IN SCHEMA anton_test_schema
REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM redshift_readonly;
```

Gives `Invalid operation: permission denied for schema anton_test_schema`. What?

If running with `anton_test_user`

```sql
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA anton_test_schema
REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM redshift_readonly;
```

As well gives `Invalid operation: permission denied for schema anton_test_schema`.

The only way for me to solve this and being able to drop `anton_test_user` was to, with `redshift_master` drop the schema and table completely

```sql
DROP TABLE anton_test_schema.anton_test_table;
DROP SCHEMA anton_test_schema;
DROP USER anton_test_user; -- it works now
```

Transfering ownership back to `anton_test_user` and then revoking default privileges did not help - dropping the table and schema was the only solution I could find.

My completely uninformed guess is that `anton_test_user` had lost permissions to the schema, so no grants for the user could be applied or revoked in that schema.

**Question(s):**

- Is there any way to avoid dropping `anton_test_schema` and `anton_test_table` while also dropping `anton_test_user`?
- Is it supposed to work this way?
- Do Postgres behave in the same way?

---

This is a bit of a follow up to a [question already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864241/redshift-cannot-drop-user-owner-default-privileges), to which I gave an answer - but I have no idea what is going on even though I came up with a "solution" ("" because dropping objects was a solution, albeit a pretty poor one). It might be that I have completely misunderstood user privileges in Redshift as well.

The original question is not completely the same as this - and I would like to know what is going on, so it is not really a repost even though it might look like it.

Comment: Odd. Not sure how much Redshift deviates from Postgres in this respect. But the safe sequence of commands to remove a role in Postgres is (as superuser): `REASSIGN OWNED BY anton_test_user TO redshift_master; DROP OWNED BY anton_test_user; DROP USER anton_test_user;` See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155356/3684

Comment: Redshift seems to be just weird, it has distorted the permission system beyond recognition.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue myself. I was able to avoid dropping the user/schema by first re-granting access of the schema to my end user (my version of `anton_test_user`).

`grant all on schema analyst_data to anton_test_user;`

After doing so, I was able to run my alter default privileges command
`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for user <user> in schema <schema> REVOKE ALL on tables FROM group <group>;`

Your uninformed guess was spot on

Comment: I want to drop the user but not the schema - tried your suggestion but unfortunately without luck.

Comment: This worked for me. As part of dropping the user I was first revoking all privileges on the schema, then trying to alter default. So I think those need to be done in the reverse order.